# Parallel ForEach using up very little processing power as time elapses

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I have the following code running and as time passes by (an hour or two)  i notice that it takes longer and longer to iterate through the items. Is there something that i'm doing which is causing this to occur? If so how can i fix it?

```
        int totalProcessed = 0;
        int totalRecords = MyList.Count();

        Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, totalRecords), (range, loopState) =>
        {
            for (int index = range.Item1; index < range.Item2; index++)
            {
                DoStuff(MyList.ElementAt(index));
                Interlocked.Increment(ref totalImported);
                if (totalImported % 1000 == 0)
                    Log(String.Format("Processed {0} of {1} records",totalProcessed, totalRecords));
            }
        });

         public void DoStuff(IEntity entity)
         {
              foreach (var client in Clients)
              {
                  // Add entity to a db using EF
                  client.Add(entity);
              }
          }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you post some details about what happens inside "DoStuff"?

Comment: okay i've edited my code to include what happens inside of "DoStuff".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ElementAt` is very slow extension method with following implementation:

```
public static void T ElementAt(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int index) 
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T e in collection)
    {
        if(i == index)
        {
            return e;
        }
        i++;
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
}
```

It is obvious that it works longer when index is greater. You should use indexer `MyList[index]` instead of `ElementAt`.

Comment: +1 I've seen a couple of people being tripped up by ElementAt recently. It should come with a health warning.

Answer (score 4):

As @mace has pointed out using `ElementAt` has performance issues. Every time you call this an iterator starts at the beginning of `MyList` and skips n elements until it gets to the desired index. This get cumulatively worse as the index position gets higher.

If you still need streaming access to `MyList`, you can mitigate performance issue by using `Skip` and `Take`. There will still be some performance impacting as you seek to a position in `MyList`, but `Take` will ensure you get a batch of elements once you get there, rather than doing this for *every* element.

I also notice that you are using the partition style foreach, but you are doing this for the whole range. I have implemented partition style with batching in the example below.

```
int totalRecords = MyList.Count();
int batchSize = 250;

Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, totalRecords, batchSize), range =>
{
    foreach (var thing in MyList.Skip(range.Item1).Take(batchSize))
    {
        DoStuff(thing);

        //logging and stuff...           
    }
});
```

**Update**

Having read the question again, you may also have problems with too many threads being used for what is probably an IO bound problem i.e. network and then DB\disk. I say this as you say that there is little CPU utilization, that leads me to think that you are blocked on IO and that this is getting progressively worse.

If it was purely down to `ElementAt`, you would still see high CPU utilization.

Configure `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to tune the maximum number of threads to use:

```
const int BatchSize = 250;

int totalRecords = MyList.Count();
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, totalRecords, BatchSize);
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, range =>
{
    foreach (int thing in MyList.Skip(range.Item1).Take(BatchSize))
    {
        DoStuff(thing);

        //logging and stuff...           
    }
});
```